# Flutter: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' (flutter_tts)

Tags: android, flutter, asynchronous, text-to-speech

So I have been using the flutter_tts module and the text to be converted into speech is repeated continuously and eventually the app crashes.
I think its something about the improper use of the keyword "Future" but since I'm a newbie, I'd like help a lot. The app I'm trying to implement is a currency recognition app for the blind so eventually the app is supposed to say "200 rupees" if the note shown to it is a 200 rupee note.
The detection is working fine, the app continuously repeats "200 rupees" and then crashes. Help please, would mean a lot. The title is the error I'm getting. I have heard async should return Future and stuff but haven't yet got the gist of it.

> "The relevant error-causing widget was: DisplayPictureScreen
> file:///C:/Android/tflite_example/lib/main.dart:122:49" Along with the
> error i got this.

```
    import 'dart:io';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final cameras = await availableCameras();
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;
  
  

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ),
  );
}


class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  const TakePictureScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.camera,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TakePictureScreenState createState() => _TakePictureScreenState();
}

class _TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Center(child: Text('Noteify'))),
      // Wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner
      // until the controller has finished initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              child: FittedBox(
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                  // Provide an onPressed callback.
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
                    // catch the error.
                    try {
                      // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
                      await _initializeControllerFuture;

                      // Construct the path where the image should be saved using the
                      // pattern package.
                      final path = join(
                        // Store the picture in the temp directory.
                        // Find the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
                        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
                        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
                      );

                      // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved.
                      await _controller.takePicture(path);

                      // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(path),
                        ),
                      );
                    } catch (e) {
                      // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A widget that displays the picture taken by the user.
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  DisplayPictureScreen(this.imagePath);
  @override
  _DisplayPictureScreenState createState() => _DisplayPictureScreenState();
}

class _DisplayPictureScreenState extends State<DisplayPictureScreen> {
  final FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
  List op;
  bool _loading;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;

    loadModel().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Image img = Image.file(File(widget.imagePath));
    classifyImage(widget.imagePath);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Center(child: img)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            op != null
                ?
            runTextToSpeech(op[0]["label"])
                : Text("No note detected"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  classifyImage(String image) async {
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image,
      numResults: 5,
      threshold: 0.2,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
    );
    setState(() {
      op = output;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

   Future<dynamic> runTextToSpeech(String outputMoney) async {
    await flutterTts.speak(outputMoney);
  }

  loadModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/model_unquant.tflite",
      labels: "assets/labels.txt",
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    Tflite.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `Future<dynamic>`  to `Future<Widget>` 
It's just a matter of not returning the correct type with the future. From what I can tell you are returning a widget with image after upload, thus the future function for handling this event needs to be of type widget. Hope that works, best of luck!

Comment: No bro I am still getting the same error.. Future<Widget> is not a subtype of type "Widget'.. The audio is being repeated and the app goes to the red page showing the above mentioned error.